# Does Spamassassin require compilation to use?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spamassassin

From what I have been able to gather, spamassassin is written in perl but there may also be compiled versions of it. Does one have to compile it inorder to use it? Can a perl script simply include spam assassin and start calling its functions/services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to compile spamassassin since it is a Perl script like you mentioned. However, you can configure the [SpamAssassin Daemon](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.0.x/dist/spamd/README) to increase the throughput performance and configure the spamassassin script to use it. The spamd daemon is useful in a web hosting environment.